# EGit 4.1 Error during Eclipse Install

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, egit, jgit

I am creating an Eclipse plugin that is relying on the latest version of [EGet found here](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/).

In the plugin.xml of my project, I add the 4.1 version to my "required dependencies"

[image]

I thought this would fix my issue when trying to run the code.

However, I am now receiving this error when I am trying to install the software:

[image]

The reason I am doing this is because of the following exception I have received:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.egit.core.project.RepositoryMapping.getMapping(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IProject;)Lorg/eclipse/egit/core/project/RepositoryMapping;
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:62)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:825)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:701)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$6(HandledContributionItem.java:685)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:613)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Has anyone encountered this before? Any guidance on resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add the bundles EGit depends on, find the list of dependencies of the org.eclipse.egit.ui bundle in its OSGi manifest:
http://git.eclipse.org/c/egit/egit.git/tree/org.eclipse.egit.ui/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

The complete list of all dependencies and the p2 repositories they can be installed from can be found in EGit's target platform for the respective platform version, e.g. for Mars (Eclipse 4.5) :
http://git.eclipse.org/c/egit/egit.git/tree/org.eclipse.egit.target/egit-4.5.target